# Concatentate all rows / alt. find using a regex across all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| id |                       value                       |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | My favourite website is http://stackoverflow.com/ |
|  2 | This text doesn't have a link! :(                 |
|  3 | Hi! A link! http://www.google.com/                |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

But of course with many rows. What I really want is a list of all the URLs in the fields. In reality they are blog posts, so some will have more than one link. I'm only interested in external links (i.e. start with (/http(s)?/) ).

So, my first thought was to perform a SQL query that returns something like:

```
My favourite website is http://stackoverflow.com/,This text doesn't have a link! :(,Hi! A link! http://www.google.com/
```

so I can use regex in PHP.

**How do I write that query?**

Alternatively, it would be great to go straight to list of URLs with SQL, but I suspect that might be too hard due to the multiple links thing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( value  )
FROM   tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aac70/2)

OTHER SOURCE

- [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Why didn't I think of doing this? I use GROUP_CONCAT all the time! Think the cold must be freezing my brain! Any ideas about whether I can also do the regex in SQL?

Comment: there are functions for [Regular Expression in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) but i don't think it fits here. hehe

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought - matching = yep, but then returning matches seems to be nope. Thanks. Hopefully noone I work with notices that I posted this question!

Comment: Actually, Guess I could narrow down the return string by specifying something like WHERE value LIKE '%http$'. Perhaps that would mean I had less memory/data exchange.

Comment: Some sql functions like `GROUP_CONCAT` is not usually taught :)

Comment: Turns out that there is a length limit for this, so it's not really going to work for me (I can override it, but I need it to be huge.) Oh well.

Comment: @RichBradshaw yep, GROUP_CONCAT has a limit.